# Running SesameWindowsClient in mono 4.0

Tags: mono, semantic-web, sesame, ubuntu-12.04

Tried 'mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 SesameWindowsClient.exe' because I wanted to run that program from konsole to get more details than from the w5 point-and-click desktop.

Ubuntu precise 12.04, tells he needs libgluezilla for that (think libgluezilla calls may be have origin in libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil), but that package is not in precise. I downloaded and installed it, but the program keeped crashing. Tried to download a custom libgluezilla to compile it manually, but can't find it. Thought of compiling manually mono, but I'm not sure it would help because precise's mono package seems not to be very old. Found a near about it post in this portal, but about Mac OS. Bit of stuck.

Comment: SWC developer here. Sorry, but we're no longer actively supporting Mono compatibility (nor, to be honest, doing much about .Net development beyond urgent bug fixes). Building this tool in .Net was one of the worst mistake I ever made, it's a nice framework but platform independence is not one of its strong points...

Comment: Now I recognize you and have to say thanks again.